# Rerendering React props.children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this kind of a setup:

```
// inside  Parent.js
class Parent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return { this.props.children }
    }
}

// inside Child.js
class Child extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let message;
        const greet = this.context.store.parentState.greet;
        if(greet) message = 'Hello, world!';
        return (
            <div>
                { message }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
Child.contextTypes = {
    store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}



// inside App.js
<Parent>
    <Route path='/a-path' component={ Child } />
</Parent>
```

When `Parent` receives new state through `setState`, its `render` method is called but the `render` method in `Child` is not called!

The reason I want to achieve that is because some logic in `Child` is dependent on the state of `Parent`.

If I pass the state of `Parent` via `context` like how the `store` is passed and then access it in `Child` via `this.context.parentState`, this seems to be working and causing a call on `Child`'s `render` method, I guess it's because we're receiving new `context`.

Why is this? `context` is great but is there a good way around this particular issue without needing `context`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are rendering components as children, which aren't components to Route, you can make use of `React.cloneElement` with `React.Children.map` like

```
// inside  Parent.js
class Parent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => 
               React.cloneElement(child, {parentState: this.state.parentState})
        );
    }
}
```

However if elements rendered as Children to Parent are Routes then either you need to make use of context or write a wrapper around `Route` so that any extra props that the Route receives are passed on to the component

```
const RouteWrapper = ({exact, path, component: Component, anyOtherRouterProp, ...rest}) => 
      <Route exact={exact} path={path} {...otherRouterProps} render={(props) => <Component {...props} {...rest} />} />
```

Where in the above case `anyOtherRouterProp` are the props that are applicable to the `Route` and needs to be destructured separately. After this you can make use of React.Children.map and React.cloneElement to pass on the props to children.

Although this is one such way, I would still recommend you to make use of context, specially with the introduction of `new context API` which makes it extremely easy to implement

Comment: response much appreciated @Shubham Khatri. Quite an amount to learn here :). I think as you noted `context` is more appropriate for this issue. Besides that, is it exhaustive to assert that a component is re-rendered only on receiving new `props`, `context`, or state via `setState`??

Comment: **Besides that, is it exhaustive to assert that a component is re-rendered only on receiving new props, context, or state via setState??** Not necessarily, because someone can just call forceUpdate to trigger a re-render, apart from that if the parent rerenders, all the children will also trigger their render method unless they are PureComponents

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this....

```
   // inside  Parent.js       
   class Parent extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
              <Child children={this.props.children} />
            )
        }
    }

    // inside Child.js
    class Child extends React.Component {
        render() {
            let message;
            const greet = this.context.store.parentState.greet;
            if(greet) message = 'Hello, world!';
            return (
                <div>
                    { message }
                    { this.props.children }
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
    Child.contextTypes = {
        store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    }



    // inside App.js
    <Parent>
        <Route path='/a-path' component={ Child } />
    </Parent>
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I want to avoid using `Child` inside of `Parent` because `Parent` can have more than just `Child` as children.

Comment: for that you can use redux or flux.